# How to find out the "current executing point" of a C# async method

Tags: c#, async-await

If a complex async method "doesn't return" (quotes means it is a metaphore and an async method return immediately, see examples bellow) how to find out where it is currently executing? For example:

```
    //normal method
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    //async method
    async private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
```

When normal method button1_Click doesn't return and "Break All" in Visual Studio then the thread will stop at "Thread.Sleep" which is exactly where it is currently executing.

But when async method button2_Click doesn't return and "Break All" the thread will stop at "Application.Run(new Form1());" instead of "Task.Delay", not giving any clue about the problematic code.

I know why it work like this way and break at "Application.Run(new Form1());". The question is **is there a good method to locate where an asyn method is "currently exucuting"**? Without such a method, the only way seems to be set break points at every such invocations then it will break at some of them.

Comment: The same could also happen by using 'normal' threads. There are two debug-windows here that could help, the list of the threads and the list of the tasks. You can find them both in the Debug menu (not sure where exactly). By double-clicking a thread in the list the debugger will show the currently interrupted statement on that thread. The task list should also give you a hint, which tasks are executing/waiting.

Comment: "The task list should also give you a hint, which tasks are executing/waiting" That seems to be the answer.